# Adding property to entity framework class

Tags: wpf, database, entity-framework

For my wpf app using entity framework, I need to add a entity property to one of the entity class . Ex: Have a many to many relation, with two tables and a juction table .

Customer: ID, name, address . 
Product: ID, name

CustomerProduct : CustomerID, ProductID

I am trying to add to my auto generated entity data class Cutomer, a property  colProducts as follows :

```
    public partial class Customer
{
    public Products  colProducts;
    public Products ColProducts
    {
        get { return colProducts; }
        set 
        {
            colProducts = ???? 
        }
    }

}
```

But I  find the relation missing . What is wrong here ?? how can i get the Products related to the customer.   I am doing this to facilitate wpf databinding.

Answer (score 0):

First, Entity will create these associations if they exists in the database (Foreign Key, or many-to-many tables). If you have control of the database, you should do this. It is simpler than the manual entity method, and helps the database stay valid.

If you can't, or don't want to, you can manually create entity associations. These steps taken [from here](http://www.overroot.com/blog/2011/04/10/how-to-manually-add-association-in-entity-framework/)

1. In EF designer select any of the two entities and select the ‘Add Association’ option in the right click menu.
2. Specify the multiplicity on each side appropriately and create the association
3. Select the association and select “Table Mapping” option
4. Now select the table that contains the foreign key column i.e. Messages
5. In column list it will show primary key of referenced table next to it select the corresponding foreign key i.e. ConversationId in our case
6. Delete the foreign key property from the referencing entity i.e ConversationId property in Messages Entity

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have already the association to CustomerProducts , but I want  to overide the entity class by adding the products attributes. So that I can have it under a single class. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, but it is not a good idea. You should use the navigation properties while in context, or use `Include()` during your query to ensure they get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

EF should generate proper many-to-many relation if CustomerID and ProductID form a composite primary key for table CustomerProduct.